# I was tricked into a terrible promotion

Tags: communication

I was asked multiple times to take a position on another shift. I didn't want to leave 1st shift, but was convinced I'd like it. In the meeting that discussed everything I asked that if I didn't like it or otherwise wished to, I'd be able to return to my old position.

Well it was bad. They lied about the duties I'd have to preform (it's like 2.5 peoples worth of work) and there's a lot of getting on your knees (which as a heavy guy is absolutely killing me).

I went to HR and explained that I was lied to and that I was promised my old spot back if I wanted. Now I know I wouldn't be moved back the next day, it may take a week or even 2. However she's now telling me I can go back to first, but in a different position...

I have seniority on nearly everyone in the factory, I was promised I could have it back, I was lied to about my job duties in order to trick me into the position. Given all of this, how are they able to deny me my old position?

I even do addition work for the company. normally the hours are 8 hours a day mon-fri, but I come in every Saturday to do maintenance. I've been taught several things few know and would consider myself an asset to the company.

How should I approach them about this? I'm trying not to get angry, but it's getting kind of hard at this point. What should I do?

Comment: I think the possible answers to your question really depend on which country you're in. Please add a country tag to your question.

Comment: It also depends on if you are in a union shop or have a contract that makes your seniority have any practical value.

Comment: Do you have any of the original promises/agreement in writing ? E-mail, paper, text etc ?

Comment: @MrGurdil And state as well, if in the US

Comment: Unless you have a legally binding contract stating such, or you have union protections in place, your employer can do or say just about anything they want.

Comment: Stop - doing additional, unpaid work. Start - polishing your CV/resume & looking for a better life.

Answer (score 7):

> I have seniority on nearly everyone in the factory

Seniority mattering usually indicates that you belong to a union. That is probably where you want to start with regard to how they are able to deny you your old position. So much of this revolves around specific rules which we do not know.

Answer (score 5):

You mentioned you work in a factory - do you have a union? It might be worth getting in touch with them. This can be very region specific.

---

**Start brushing up your CV.**

It may not be what you want to hear, but at the end of the day, they can probably move you to whatever position in the company they want to and just did you a courtesy asking you to move rather than demanding it. In order to get your old position back, you may need to be ready to walk out over it.

The good news it, it sounds like you are an asset to the company and that may mean that they want to keep you on and speed up the process of moving you back if they realise they may lose you over it.

The only other avenue you can go down is checking any documentation, but I think it's a long shot! Does your contact state the position you are meant to be in and the work you're meant to be doing? Did you sign a new contract for the new position and if so, do you have it in writing that they guaranteed your old position should you find the new one unsuitable?

Answer (score 1):

Giving you your old position back may be difficult if whoever has been doing it is doing it really well and they want to keep them there.

I assume the offered first shift position is in some way inferior to your old position. Can you negotiate changes that would make it a good one for you?